# WebApi and MVC controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm planning to have both MVC and WebAPI functionality in my application. There's going to be an administration site implemented with simple MVC CRUD controllers and I also need a RESTful API to be called from the remote client and possibly from a single page app in the future.
I'm not too comfortable with writing very similar classes that differ only in return type - MVC controllers returning data wrapped in a View and WebAPI controllers simply returning data unwrapped.
What would be the best way to achieve my goals without repeating too much code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, if you're using WebAPI, your standard MVC controllers shouldn't be used for CRUD. Your API controllers should handle CRUD operations and your MVC controllers should return views.

By going this route, it gives you a couple of different options as to how you'll display data in your views:

**TRADITIONAL**

If you want to stick with a more "traditional" route, you can invoke your WebAPI controllers server side from your MVC controller, hydrate a model object and return a strongly typed view. You can do this by using the [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158944.aspx) class or the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to make your API calls and deserializing the response.

**SINGLE PAGE**

If you want to try a more "modern" route, you can try what danludwig suggested and build more of a single page app. In this scenario, your MVC controller will just return a HTML + JavaScript view that relies on a client-side framework to make API calls and update the DOM. The [require](http://requirejs.org/) + [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) + [knockback](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/)/[knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) stack is a great place to start but it does have a bit of a learning curve.

Either way, you really should only have CRUD logic in one place, and I believe this belongs in the API.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to have your MVC controllers not return strongly typed viewmodels. Instead they could return plain HTML + javascript that could use something like backbone or knockout to invoke your Api action methods and populate the DOM.